# Getting pspell or any spell checker to work in wamp

Tags: php, wamp, spell-checking, pspell

I've been trying to install a php spell checker in my version of wamp and it's just not happening.
I've uncommented lines of the php ini, reinstalled wamp with an updated version of php and basically no luck. 
At present I get the line.
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'php_pspell.dll' in Unknown on line 0

So looks like I've got the wrong version of pspell in my extensions.

Can someone give me a really easy to follow way to add this in.
I've been trying to get Enchant to work as well.
All to no avail - can someone help.

Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 0):

Seems there haven't been much movement around, right?
Anyway, not sure if you're still looking for a solution here, but I have more or less the same problem. There doesn't seems to be a solution for pspell for PHP 5.3+, but enchant does seem to work.

I have a system that uses pspell for spell checking, and there doesn't seem to be any available version of that file that runs with any version of PHP running in wamp above 5.3 (I think it has to do with the VC version used to compile the system).

Now, regarding the problem you have with enchant, I managed to make it work in wamp just by un commenting the line in php.ini

As there are no indications from your input of what could be wrong, here you have a couple of things you could do to troubleshoot:

- After enabling the enchant extension and restarting wamp, create a php file that has only the instruction `phpinfo();` on it, and access it through a browser. Search for the string 'enchant' there. that will give you an indication if the extension was loaded or not
- If the extension was not loaded, try to run, from a command box, the following line: `<%path_to_your_php_exe%>/php.exe -c <%path_to_your_php_ini%>/php.ini -v`

When there's a problem with any of the extension you'll get that either as a message in the command line or in a pop up, something that does not happen in wamp (It does happen if you start apache from the command line).

I hope this helps. Good luck.